# Get Direct Messages Twitter iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios5, twitter

How can we get direct messages in twitter? i am using iOS 5, i have created the app from twitter, sets the permission to read,write, DM, created the auth.token etc. But which API i should call to fetch the DMs from twitter account in iOS 5.